# Error "503 Service Unavailable" for sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I have this problem when I use `apt-get update`:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                    
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/compiz/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                                        
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
W: Fallo al obtener http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 200.35.32.3 80]
W: Fallo al obtener http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 200.35.32.3 80]
W: Fallo al obtener http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 200.35.32.3 80]
W: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
```

Somebody can help me.
thanks!

Comment: Did you check the PPAs supported bionic; http://ppa.launchpad.net/compiz/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ shows it's very very old, unmaintained and I wouldn't want to trust it (let alone not supporting bionic).  Check to avoid these errors, but more importantly for security reasons (PPA's are 3rd party so you are responsible for the checks! not Ubuntu or Canonical)

Comment: `503` indicates a server error. I just visited these URLs myself and they seem to work fine now. Maybe it was just a temporary problem on their side? Please try again. Btw. you can get English output for posting here or on other forums by prefixing your command with `LANG=C`, like `LANG=C sudo apt update`

Comment: @guiverc That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the issue here.

Comment: Maverick was 10.10, with support for the PPA ending in 2011.  It's a few years past then, and I'd hope someone would detect & realize something that wasn't updated since  2010 is somewhat risky in 2019.  @ByteCommander   (*with multiple errors I picked one, the PPA was what I looked up and linked thus what my comment applied to*)

Comment: @guiverc Fair, I didn't examine that one specifically, but mostly the others. Anyway, the error would not be 503 but 404 and with different text if it were just about the release not being supported. You are of course right though that this PPA should not be used any more, even if it doesn't change the problem in question.